# silverlight wcf and custom username and password

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, web-services

I have a silverlight application.  I have many wcf files hosted by iis 6.  I have a custom username/password store.

What is the best way to secure the wcf?

Also I will have a third party desktop app call this WCF as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see followng link 
http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/alexb/archive/2009/10/02/silverlight-3-securing-your-wcf-service-with-a-custom-username-and-password-authentication-mechanism.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an example using a custom validator](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/07/14/silverlight-wcf-amp-transportwithmessagecredential-security.aspx).